# Data didn't show on my view, how to solve it?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

This Is My UserController

```
public function anggota()
    {
        $members = Anggota::orderBy('name','ASC')->paginate(5);
        return view('user.member',[
            'members'=>$members]);
    }    
public function showmember(Anggota $anggota)
    {
        $anggota = Anggota::find($anggota);
        return view('user.single-member', compact('anggota'));
    }
```

This is my index view

```
@extends('layouts.navbar')
@section('content')
<section id="hero" class="d-flex">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section-title" data-aos="fade-up">
            <h2>Anggota</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
                <table class="display" id="data_member" width="100%" data-aos="fade-up">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>No</th>
                            <th>Nama</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        @forelse ($members as $member)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
      
                            <td>{{$member->name}}</td>
                            <td>
                            <a href="{{route('member.show', $member->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Detail</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>   
                        @empty
                            <td>No record</td>
                        @endforelse
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    {!! $members->links() !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

After I click detail button, It move to single-member page for show detail and data didn't show

This is my Show View

```
@extend('layouts.navbar')    
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between">
        <a href="{{route('member.anggota')}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark">Kembali</a>
    </div>

        <div class="card-body">

          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              @foreach ( $anggota as $member )
              <tr>
                <th>Nama Lengkap :</th>
                <th>{{$member->name}}</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Tanggal Lahir :</th>
                <th>{{$member->tgl_lhr}}</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Alamat :</th>
                <th>{{$member->address}}</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Instagram :</th>
                <th>{{$member->ig}}</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
              @endforeach
          </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

this is my reoute

```
Route::get('member',[\App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController::class, 'anggota'])->name('member.anggota');
Route::get('single-member',[\App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController::class, 'showmember']) >name('member.show');
```

with thats code, I didn't found any error but data didn't showed on my view. how to solve it? if I change the controller from Anggota::find($anggota) to Anggota::all() that show all data, not show data which choosen

Comment: you did not pass the member but calling in the view.

Comment: the route is missing the `-` near to the `name()` .. post your code correct so we can help you!

Comment: I've put all now

Comment: You didn't add dynamic argument for show page in route

Comment: 'single-member/{member}'

Answer (score 1):

Your route needs a [required parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#required-parameters)

```
Route::get('single-member/{anggota}',[\App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController::class, 'showmember'])->name('member.show');
```

Then in your controller, if you use [dependency injection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#dependency-injection) (using `showmember(Anggota $anggota)`) then you dont need to fetch the model.

```
public function showmember(Anggota $anggota)
{
    return view('user.single-member', compact('anggota'));
}
```

If you dont want to use dependency injection, remove the class in the method call.

```
public function showmember($anggota)
{
    $anggota = Anggota::find($anggota);
    return view('user.single-member', compact('anggota'));
}
```